# Why does unshare binary call clone() so many times?

Tags: namespace, unshare, clone

I am trying to test the `unshare` command in Linux. I am using it to create a new user namespace. I tried the following test:

```
user1@myPC$ strace -e clone,unshare,fork,execve unshare --user
execve("/usr/bin/unshare", ["unshare", "--user"], [/* 71 vars */]) = 0
unshare(CLONE_NEWUSER)                  = 0
execve("/bin/bash", ["-bash"], [/* 71 vars */]) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0xb7275768) = 9153
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=9153, si_uid=65534, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0xb7275768) = 9155
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=9155, si_uid=65534, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0xb7275768) = 9160
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=9160, si_uid=65534, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0xb7275768) = 9162
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=9162, si_uid=65534, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0xb7275768) = 9164
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=9164, si_uid=65534, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0xb7275768) = 9167
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=9167, si_uid=65534, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
nobody@MyPC:~$
```

I want to ask why are there so many calls to `clone()` made ?

Comment: All of them are after execve(/bin/bash), so it's bash doing them, not unshare. It's probably fork()ing when running the commands from ~/.bashrc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unshare(1)` is not calling `clone(2)` at all. After calling the `unshare(CLONE_NEWUSER)` system call, the `unshare` program is exec'ing through to the program given on the command line or the program from the `$SHELL` environment variable.

In your case, that's `bash`, which is fork-ing a lot (`fork(2)` is a wrapper for `clone(2)` nowadays) while processing the commands from its initialization scripts (`~/.bashrc`, etc).